# Programmatically Disable All Keyboard Input Globally

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard

I'm writing a Mac menubar app to disable various functionality at the click of a menu item. One of said menu items is to globally disable all keyboard input while retaining trackpad/mouse clicks. I've searched through Apple's dev docs and here and haven't found anything.

I already have my menu options set up and the click actions functioning correctly, but I don't know how to access the keyboard and thus disable it globally. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I tried the following:

```
if(keyboardEnabled){
     NSLog("Keyboard Disabled")
     keyboardEnabled = false
     let source = CGEventSource(stateID: .hidSystemState)
     let keyboard = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: 0, keyDown: false)
     keyboard?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
 }else{
     NSLog("Keyboard Enabled")
     keyboardEnabled = true
     let source = CGEventSource(stateID: .hidSystemState)
     let keyboard = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: source, virtualKey: 0, keyDown: true)
     keyboard?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)       
}
```

I expected the keyboard to be disabled, but it was still active.